# Runtime.getRuntime().exec problem win serv 2003 versus win serv 2008

Tags: java, windows-server-2008, runtime.exec

I have some java code as follows:

```
try {
  String outString ="java -jar C:\\ami\\bin\\ImmediateSubmit.jar 12345 localhost";
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(outString);
  out.println("SUBMITTED");
} 
catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("IO Exception parse");
  out.println("FAILED");
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

It works fine in win serv 2003 but not in win serv 2008.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Any clues - like an error message or anything? Could be cosmic rays

Comment: No error messages.    It's not hitting the catch block.   And it doesn't matter what I try to execute.   I tried a simple toy batch file and it did not execute either.

Comment: Why don't you replace ImmediateSubmit.jar with a HelloWorld.jar to see if your stuck trying to connect to localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read both the [stdout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29) and [stderr](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream%28%29) streams of the [`Process`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) returned by `Runtime#exec()`.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();
```

This will return whatever you'd normally see when entering the command plain in command prompt, including errors. Your answer may be in there. Long story short: [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html), this is an excellent article explaining its pitfalls in depth. Read all the 4 pages. It contains helpful code snippets.

My *guess* is that either `java` isn't recognized as a command (e.g. missing in `%PATH%`), or that it's an user permission issue. At least, that are the most common causes in cases like that.

Comment: This was very helpful and allowed me to debug the problem.   Thank you!